# CometD taking more time in pushing messages

Tags: javascript, cometd

I am trying to implement CometD in our application. But it is taking more time compared to the existing implementation in our project. The existing system is taking time in milliseconds where as CometD is taking 2 seconds to push the message.

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Any guidance will help me lot.

My code:

Java script at client side

```
  (function($)
{
var cometd = $.cometd;

$(document).ready(function()
{
    function _connectionEstablished()
    {
        $('#body').append('<div>CometD Connection Established</div>');
    }

    function _connectionBroken()
    {
        $('#body').append('<div>CometD Connection Broken</div>');
    }

    function _connectionClosed()
    {
        $('#body').append('<div>CometD Connection Closed</div>');
    }

    // Function that manages the connection status with the Bayeux server
    var _connected = false;
    function _metaConnect(message)
    {
        if (cometd.isDisconnected())
        {
            _connected = false;
            _connectionClosed();
            return;
        }

        var wasConnected = _connected;
        _connected = message.successful === true;
        if (!wasConnected && _connected)
        {
            _connectionEstablished();
        }
        else if (wasConnected && !_connected)
        {
            _connectionBroken();
        }
    }

    // Function invoked when first contacting the server and
    // when the server has lost the state of this client
    function _metaHandshake(handshake)
    {
        if (handshake.successful === true)
        {
            cometd.batch(function()
            {
                cometd.subscribe('/java/test', function(message)
                {
                    $('#body').append('<div>Server Says: ' + message.data.eventID + ':'+ message.data.updatedDate + '</div>');
                });

            });
        }
    }

    // Disconnect when the page unloads
    $(window).unload(function()
    {
        cometd.disconnect(true);
    });

    var cometURL = "http://localhost:8080/cometd2/cometd";
    cometd.configure({
        url: cometURL,
        logLevel: 'debug'
    });

    cometd.addListener('/meta/handshake', _metaHandshake);
    cometd.addListener('/meta/connect', _metaConnect);

    cometd.handshake();
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comet service class

```
    @Listener("/service/java/*")
    public void processMsgFromJava(ServerSession remote, ServerMessage.Mutable message)
    {

    Map<String, Object> input = message.getDataAsMap();
    String eventId = (String)input.get("eventID");
    //setting msg id

   String channelName = "/java/test";
    // Initialize the channel, making it persistent and lazy
    bayeux.createIfAbsent(channelName, new ConfigurableServerChannel.Initializer()
    {
        public void configureChannel(ConfigurableServerChannel channel)
        {
            channel.setPersistent(true);
            channel.setLazy(true);
        }
    });

    // Publish to all subscribers
    ServerChannel channel = bayeux.getChannel(channelName);
    channel.publish(serverSession, input, null);


}
```

Is there any thing I need to change in server side code.

Answer (score 1):

You have made your channel lazy, so a delay in message broadcasting is expected (that is what lazy channels are all about).

Please have a look at the [documentation for lazy channels](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/java_server.html#java_server_lazy_messages).

If you want immediate broadcasting don't set the channel as lazy.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I tried in two ways setting channel.setLazy as false and removed that line channel.setLazy even then I didnt find any change in time taking to push the message. Anything else I need to do. Please guide me.

Comment: Hi, One more thing I forgot to mention. If multiple clients get connected(subscribed) to same channel then the time taking to push the message to those clients are different it is taking almost 2 secs for each client i.e. if 1st client received at 10:20:30 then the last client will receive message at around 10:20:50. Why is this so. I am not able to find the reason in this case also